# Merge [patch] and [patching] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patch) has a lot of questions with a wiki like this

> A patch is a piece of software designed to fix problems with, or update a computer program or its supporting data. This includes fixing security vulnerabilities and other bugs, and improving the usability or performance.

[patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patching) is less common in usage with only 110 questions at the moment. It might refer to the act of patching, whereas the other tag refers to the patch itself, but in the end they're both about fixing something with a patch. Therefore IMHO we should make [patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patching) another synonym of [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patch)